# How to determine a QEMU virtual machine is idle?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, io

I am working on a KVM-QEMU virtual machine.
Currently I want to find out whether a program (e.g., MySql) running inside the virtual machine is idle (i.e., not busy processing requests). 
I want to get this information in the QEMU level (from the information outside the VM).
From the cpu usage of the virtual machine process, I can roughly determine whether the program has become idle if this program is CPU-intensive.
However, is there any advice on how to determine if this program is **disk IO-intensive**? Because for the IO-intensive application, if it's still busy processing requests, its CPU is not much used, I can not tell from the CPU usage. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iotop -a` to show accumulated I/O transfer for each process. From the process command line, you can infer which VM is doing heavy I/O.

Another possibility is to search, via `ps axf`, for processes in `D` or `S` state.